# Separate street and number with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I know this question comes up all the time again. But potential solutions I found are either in PHP or Java, which I do not know. I need this to work with Python.

I have streets in this format:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'street':[
    'ABC Street',
    'ABC Street 1',
    'SDF Street 1a',
    'KSD Street 30 a',
    'URR-AC Place 1-5'
]})
```

And, oh what surprise, need to separate them, so I end up with:

```
   street       number
0  ABC Street   NaN
1  ABC Street   1
2  SDF Street   1a 
3  KSD Street   30 a
4  URR-AC Place 1-5
```

My idea is not new. Look from the end of the string until you find the last number and split the string there. But with str.split I can split, but #4 will not work. I guess this is a Regex problem, but I have no clue about it.

Comment: I do not really understand, why I am downvoted on this. The question should be clear and I gave an example. So please, if you downvote, at least tell me why, so I can make it better next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for my special case, I seem to have found an answer.

First, I am making sure there are no leading/tracing spaces:

```
df.street= df.street.str.strip()
```

Then, I am extracting the street name. What the Regex does is to look for one or more non-digit characters. So once it hits the first digit it stops and thus gives me the name:

```
df['street_name'] = df.street.str.extract('(\D+)', expand=False)
```

To separate the the number, I am using the same functionality. But here I am looking for the first digit to appear and any following character.

```
df['number'] = df.street.str.extract('(\d+.*)', expand=False)
```

This then results in the following dataframe:

```
  street             street_name    number
0 ABC Street         ABC Street     NaN 
1 ABC Street 1       ABC Street     1 
2 SDF Street 1a      SDF Street     1a 
3 KSD Street 30 a    KSD Street     30 a 
4 URR-AC Place 1-5   URR-AC Place   1-5
```

Caution: This will fail when you have a street name like "Strasse-des-17. Juli, 5", where a number is part of the name.